# How can you cast between wchar_t* and an int?

Tags: c++, casting

I have a function which returns the inner text of an xml element.  It returns it, however, as a `const wchar_t*`.  I wish to return this value as an integer (And a float in some other cases).  What is the best method for doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ way would be:

```
wchar_t* foo = L"123";
std::wistringstream s(foo);
int i = 0;
s >> i;
```

With Boost, you could do:

```
try {
    int i2 = boost::lexical_cast<int>(foo);
} catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast const&) {
    ...
}
```

Depending on which CRT implementation you're using you may have "wide" `atoi`/`strtol` functions:

```
int i = _wtoi(foo);
long l = _wcstol(foo, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  What would be the proper way to catch this exception?  Or just a generic exception handler?

Comment: @Chris Updated with exception handing example.

Comment: Boost defines `class bad_lexical_cast : public std::bad_cast`, just catch it as any other exception.

Comment: Question, does this wistringstream work for floats as well?  Trying to avoid including boost in my project :)

Comment: @Chris Yes, both the C++ and Boost solutions work fine for `float`, `double`, `long long`, etc..  (Of course, you need to change the `<int>` to `<float>` or whatever in the Boost example, or wrap it in a templated function call to infer the correct type).  Both solutions can also be extended to work for your own custom types, as well by defining an overload of `operator<<` and a template specialization, respectively.

Comment: Wonderful.  And I do not need to close these streams at all?

Comment: @Chris The `std::wistringstream` object makes a copy of the input string and cleans itself up when it goes out of scope.  There's no need to call `close` or anything, though you may want to check the state of the stream after the extraction to see whether it was successful.  If something goes wrong, e.g. parsing "NaN", then `s.fail()` will be true.  If the entire input is processed, `s.eof()` will be true, as opposed to parsing, e.g., "123x" where `eof()` and `fail()` will both be false.

Comment: @Chris You can shortcut this by doing `if((s >> i).fail())` (or equivalently `if(!(s >> i))`) or `if(s >> i)` to detect whether any value was set into `i`.

Answer (score 3):

1) manual parsing (using `sprintf` & `atof`/`atoi` for instance)

2) using `boost::lexical_cast` (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm)

3) using string streams (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/)